# Storing a List<Tt> with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, c#-4.0

I'm expecting a firm no here, but is there any way to store a List< int > (or float or string) within SQLite?

I've searched around and can't seem to find anything.

Comment: By inserting a `List<int> ` in SQLLite you mean the values of the List or you are really asking for how to serialize the `List<int>` to be able to store it in a database? Please explain.

Comment: I have a list< int > of something. What I need to do is serialise that list and put that into the database.

Answer (score -1):

Object Relational Mapping (ORM) tools will do this sort of thing, typically by creating a new table to hold instances of the list and a foreign key to connect it with the referring "object." One tool for .NET for ORM is [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).

If you are willing to forego queries referencing elements of your list, you can serialize it into a buffer, and store the buffer to the SQLite database as a blob. Of course you'll also need a deserializer to convert the blob back to a list.